# UISearchController in UITabBarController is not responding to touch

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad, uisearchcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller, which is inside of a uinavigationcontroller, and I am trying to put a searchbar in the tableviewheader on one of the tabs. I am able to successfully use the code below on any screen on the navigationcontroller but the search will not respond to touch when the view is on the tabbarcontroller. I can successfully set it to active in code but I need touch to work as well.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"SEARCH"];
[self.searchController.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"SEARCH"];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.843 green:0.843 blue:0.843 alpha:1];
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that the line `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` was the root cause of the problem (for more information: [UISearchController and definesPresentationContext](http://programmingthomas.com/blog/2014/10/5/uisearchcontroller-and-definespresentationcontext)).

Make sure that the class setting `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` is also a parent view controller of the search bar. If you're initializing the `UISearchController` using the code you provided and then assigning the search bar to a view outside the hierarchy this might be causing the problem.